# Regex: how to match overlapping patterns (maybe Python specific)

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like this: "XaXbXcX". I'm looking to match any lowercase letters surrounded by X on either side. I tried this in Python, but I'm not getting what I'm looking for:

```
import re
str = "XaXbXcX"
pattern = r'X([a-z])X'
matches = re.findall(pattern, str) # gives me ['a', 'c']. What about b?
```

Comment: In that particular case, you could have use : re.split('X', str).

Comment: @dugres: not really, if the string looked like XaXbXcXddXeeeX, the pattern would fail by returning dd and eee (and some empty string at the beginning and end).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind assertion:

```
pattern = r'(?<=X)([a-z])X'
```

Comment: I *believe* (but could be convinced otherwise) that lookbehind is a Python 2.7 feature -- which is not to criticize this solution; if you're going to go with RegExes, it's the only way.

Comment: That is incorrect, lookbehind assertions have been available since Python 2.0. http://docs.python.org/release/2.0/lib/re-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

I do not know python, however this regex works i tested in gskinner too `([^(?:X)+])+`.

Hope this helps you

Comment: the following pattern also works.. `([^X])+` give this a try too and let me know if it helps. The full regex is : `/([^(?:X)+])+/gi`

Comment: Your patterns matches all characters that "are not uppercase X", which is quite different from "all lowercase characters surrounded by an X on either side". e.g. if the string passed looks like this XaXbbXcXdXeXfXggX, it would fail, as it would also match characters b and g, even though they don't have X on *both* sides.

Comment: as i select all the characters other than X, i thought that you could useup all the matches. anyways b,g are all surrounded by X. thanks for your comment